# Autofill options on Firefox 64

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I'm looking for my autofill settings on Firefox 64.

According to the [official documentation here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/automatically-fill-address-and-credit-cards):

> 1. Click the menu button  Fx57Menu and choose Preferences.
> 2. Click the
>      Privacy & Security panel.
> 3. In the Forms & Passwords section, put a
>      check mark next to Autofill addresses to turn it on, or remove the
>      check mark to turn it off.

However, on Firefox 64 (for Ubuntu), this doesn't appear to exist:

[image]

Firefox version: 64.0(64-bit) Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical-1.0